# Caching a user's Facebook friend list

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, facebook, mongodb

I have a Rails app (running 3.2.2) and I want to cache my users' Facebook friends so that I can access in my application faster than querying the Facebook Graph API every single time.

I'm currently using ActiveRecord with MySQL (though I want to switch to DataMapper at some point).

I feel like a document store like MongoDB might work better here but I don't have much experience with NoSQL. Or should I just store them in a MySQL table called user_fb_friends, and just store `user_id` | `facebook_id` for each user's friends? Any pros and or cons to having two separate database stores?

Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL can handle the job, although if you don't need to join with any other data, you may be better off looking at [Redis](http://www.redis.io/) which is dead simple and incredibly fast.

Comment: Awesome. Installed Redis with the redis-rb gem and am kinda blown away at the ease of it. Thanks!